# Django 1.5->1.6 cannot import name zip_longest

Tags: python, django, import

I m trying to migrate my project from django version 1.5 to 1.6. I have weird import error and to be honest I do not know what to do next:

Error: **cannot import name zip_longest**

```
...
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\mysql\compiler.py in <module>
from django.db.models.sql import compiler
from django.utils.six.moves import zip_longest 
...
```

I think it's weird because the error occurs in django imports and it's not directly in my code

- Here is [Traceback](http://dpaste.com/hold/1707138/)
- My settings [file](http://dpaste.com/hold/1707159/)

I would be realy greatful for any hints how to solve it

Best regards

Comment: Reading your stacktrace, it's clearly linked to `SubdomainURLRoutingMiddleware`. If, for some reason, you don't need it anymore, try removing it. Maybe it's just not compatible with Django 1.6.

Comment: I tried to remove it but it didn'help. As we can see this error is inside django imports, and it occurs in every moment when application want to do something with database

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this error by changing django 1.6 source code... So I don't think that it's good solution

in file **django\db\backends\mysql\compiler.py**

I replaced code

```
from django.utils.six.moves import zip_longest
```

with

```
from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest
```

As I tested my application works fine with this patch

btw there is similar topic:

[import error with python-mysql-connector 1.16, django 1.6, and python 3.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546836/import-error-with-python-mysql-connector-1-16-django-1-6-and-python-3-2-3)

Comment: Works but a little bit dirty.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you have an issue with your installation of Django 1.6.2 causing a corruption in that included six module.

```
>>> from django import VERSION
>>> print(VERSION)
(1, 6, 2, 'final', 0)

>>> from django.utils.six.moves import zip_longest
>>>
```

Comment: I typed this in python shell and everything works. I will see if this error occurs on empty django project with mysql as db. Thanks