# import error with python-mysql-connector 1.16, django 1.6, and python 3.2.3

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

I'm running django-rest-framework on Django 1.6 in a virtualenv of Python 3.2.3 with a newly installed python-mysql-connector 1.1.6 via [the source](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) on a Ubuntu host.

Everything works fine when I run syncdb and start it up, but when I got to any url that isn't the root I get this import error from python-mysql-connector:

```
Exception Value:    

cannot import name zip_longest

Exception Location:     /usr/local/dev/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/compiler.py in <module>, line 6
```

Here's the line in question:

```
from django.utils.six.moves import zip_longest
```

If I activate my virtualenv python binary, I can successfully run that import statement. So what gives?

```
>>>>from django.utils.six.moves import zip_longest
>>>>
```

Here's my pip list output from my virtualenv where I plan on running Django to verify I have all the right bits installed:

```
(python3.2.3)thegooch@yrmomsapt:~/$ pip list
Django (1.6.2)
djangorestframework (2.3.13)
Markdown (2.4)
mysql-connector-python (1.1.6)
pip (1.5.4)
setuptools (2.2)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

Comment: I'm sorry for having to ask if it's plugged in, but you did install `python-mysql-connector` into your virtualenv, right? :)

Comment: Great question, I'll update my question to reflect that it is, in fact, installed in my virtualenv.

Comment: Could it be that something is causing a circular import?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can all imports all day everyday, and nothing will throw an exception unless you are importing an invalid module. I don't think it's circular since line six of the compiler.py file clearly is making that statement, but when you call that import alone it works fine.

Comment: If I make two files in a package directory, `a.py` and `b.py`, such that each says only `from a import f; def f(): pass` (or `from b...`, whichever one we're not in) and then try to run them, it gives me `ImportError: cannot import name f`.

Comment: I found this, grepping for the same import command from another module: 
(python3.2.3)thegooch@mycompy:~/$ grep -r "import zip_longest" /usr/local/dev/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/
/usr/local/dev/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/compiler.py:from django.utils.six.moves import zip_longest
/usr/local/dev/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/compiler.py:from django.utils.six.moves import zip_longest

Comment: If I don't use mysql-connector and use sqlite, it works. This is a frustrating error. Multiple files make the same import statement, what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying the code it looks like there is some kind of error when referencing that import. I looked into the /lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/utils/six.py file and found where the reference was to the moves.zip_longest module.

First was this reference:

```
moves = sys.modules[__name__ + ".moves"] = _MovedItems(__name__ + ".moves")
```

Which means it was calling the _MovedItems class, and here it is with the reference to my module that was breaking.

```
class _MovedItems(_LazyModule):
    """Lazy loading of moved objects"""

    _moved_attributes = [
        MovedAttribute("zip_longest", "itertools", "itertools", "izip_longest", "zip_longest")

class MovedAttribute(_LazyDescr):

    def __init__(self, name, old_mod, new_mod, old_attr=None, new_attr=None):
        super(MovedAttribute, self).__init__(name)
        if PY3:
            if new_mod is None:
            new_mod = name
            self.mod = new_mod
            if new_attr is None:
                if old_attr is None:
                    new_attr = name
                else:
                    new_attr = old_attr
            self.attr = new_attr
```

Which then inherits from the _LazyDescr class, but that is a short little object. I don't know where things went wrong, if you map the tuple being passed into the MovedAttribute constructor it maps correctly the old version to the new one. I'm not sure why it's failing but if you remove the import statement in the compiler.py file and simply call itertools zip_longest directly, it all works.

Here's what that looks like. If you are using Python 3, edit the /lib/python3.2/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/compiler.py file, and change line 6 from this:

```
from django.utils.six.moves import zip_longest as six_zip_longest
```

to this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
```